# When overwriting a background image, are both images downloaded?

Tags: css

Would both these images be downloaded? Is the browser smart and only downloads the last one? Will it start to download the first one and then cancel it, or will it wait until all css is loaded and then download the last image?

```
body { background:url(img/bg/bg1.png) }
body { background:url(img/bg/bg2.png) }
```

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345505/overiding-css-background-image-styles-both-images-are-loaded) a similar post on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Test it out: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8xZNY/show/

And the results:

[image]

You overwrite the `background` property with your second declaration, so no, they aren't downloaded twice. Only the last one is actually used.

Comment: Thanks Blender. You are a great software and you know some css too. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I actually didn't know, so [I tested it out](http://jsfiddle.net/yArtV/):

```
body { background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/300) }
body { background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300) }
```

It probably depends on the browser, but it seems that at least for Chrome (and logically) it parses the stylesheet *first* to determine rules that get applied, then downloads the images for applied rules.  This means that only the second image gets downloaded (the Network tab confirms this).

EDIT: Same result testing in Firefox

MORE EDIT: Same result even using the `style` attribute to set the background.  It will only download the one with the highest specificity it seems.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't expect that. Other browers support that feature as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to look up exactly how it works, but it seems like it looks at the css first. But I'm curious if it's the same for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is an interpreted language. It will execute line by line until it is finished, so yes -- it will grab both.

**Edit:**

By nature of an interpreted language, this is how it *should* work...

It seems though that there are intelligent preproccessors baked into browsers to look for things like this.

Comment: Sure about that? The others don't seem to agree.

Comment: @John It should but then browsers have CSS preproccessors that look out for things like this. Less those features, it would be grabbing them one at a time.

Comment: Interpreted doesn’t always mean it’s executed line-by-line. 99% of interpreted languages are pre-compiled in an intermediate form so there could be some optimization going on at this level.