# Overriding Twitter Bootstrap styles - Performance?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website using the Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework. Rather than host the (significantly sized) file and Font Awesome myself, I plan to use the [Bootstrap CDN by NetDNA](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) instead to get both, Bootstrap's CSS as well as Font Awesome.

However, some of the button styles in Bootstrap do not appeal to me, and I've decided to override them in a custom stylesheet.

I've already read [this question about overriding CSS styles involving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345505/overiding-css-background-image-styles-both-images-are-loaded), but does the same apply for background gradients and other assortments? (which  make my (quite old) computer groan if used too much, leading me to believe they do put some strain on the computer)

For example, one of bootstrap's style rules is as follows:

```
.btn-primary {
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background-color: #006dcc;
*background-color: #0044cc;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0044cc));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0044cc);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: #0044cc #0044cc #002a80;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0044cc', GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
```

which I'm tentatively overriding with:

```
.btn-primary {
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background-image: none;
background-color: #057CB8;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Will the earlier (**possibly** CPU intensive) properties be loaded anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser starts reading the html from the top, and starts fetching all CSS. The page will **not** be painted until all the CSS has been downloaded.

The bootstrap CSS will get loaded, but it won't be painted.

Comment: So the text will be loaded, but the styles will not be applied until it's done reading all the CSS?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas Correctomundo

Comment: Be more concerned with the size of your DOM and old IE. With a reasonable DOM, you should be fine. IE7 will start to fail quickly with a large DOM and 10,000 lines of CSS.

Comment: @VivekGhaisas Good question, this is an interesting read if you want to know more about it http://www.danolsavsky.com/article-understanding-web-browser-rendering-behaviors-to-optimze-css.html

Comment: @ScottSimpson I don't intend to support IE7. I shall make them suffer instead.

Comment: @koningdavid hmm, yes, that is quite an interesting read. I'm still left wondering though, why are the images loaded as asked in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345505/overiding-css-background-image-styles-both-images-are-loaded ?

Comment: @vivek ghaisas  Because first your css is fetched, and after that your browser will decide what images are needed

Comment: @koningdavid That's what I thought. But doesn't the answer say that the images included in the earlier styles as well as the images in overriding styles are loaded?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas Ah I see your point, but images are loaded later, even if they are in the CSS

Comment: I see. I'll wait a little more, and if I get nothing else to consider, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!